# Why is there a difference in blockchain fee between Bitcoin-Qt and blockchain API?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Today I noticed that there is a big difference in blockchain fee between Bitcoin-Qt and blockchain API.

When I get fee using blockchain API

```
bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6
{
  "feerate": 0.00149343,
  "blocks": 6
}
```

When I get fee from Bitcoin-Qt it shows 0.00032476
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoJcr.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is second parameter. Example.

bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6 ECONOMICAL